# Show only two axis values in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to show just the 2GB and the 4GB values (just 2 values) in the y-axis of this chart (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv684von/1/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Size']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 4294967296,
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var maxElement = this.axis.max;
                    var kb = 1024, mb = 1048576, gb = 1073741824;
                    if (maxElement > gb) {
                        return (this.value / gb).toFixed(1) + " GB";
                    } else if (maxElement > mb) {
                        return (this.value / mb).toFixed(1) + " MB";
                    } else if (maxElement > kb) {
                        return (this.value / kb).toFixed(1) + " KB";
                    } else {
                      return (this.value) + " B";
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + filesize(this.y);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Versioned trees',
            data: [94371840]
        }, {
            name: 'Metadata',
            data: [115343360]
        }, {
            name: 'Data',
            data: [1395864371.2]
        }]
    });
});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you just filter the data before you provide it to highcharts?

Comment: @Canvas - How would that format the y axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `tickPositions` property, like this:

```
tickPositions:[0, 1073741824 * 2, 1073741824 * 4]
```

It doesn't appear to respect the `min:0` if you don't include 0, but you can hide the 0 label by adding:

```
showFirstLabel: false
```

Updated Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/kv684von/2/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions